Is there an Alexandrov topological group for which the topology is not discrete?
A topological space is Alexandrov if the arbitrary intersection of open sets is open. I know for a fact that there are non-discrete Alexandrov spaces, e.g. the Sierpinski space. I'm wondering however, if there can be a topological group that is Alexandrov without being discrete.
ETA: I know that for topological groups that $T_0$ and $T_1$ are the same. Moreover, any $T_1$ Alexandrov space is necessarily discrete.

Yes, indiscrete one for example. If you allow only $T_2$ topological groups then no.

In fact, for topological groups $T_0$ and $T_{3.5}$ are the same.

Any non-trivial ones, or is this a pipe dream?

Take any normal subgroup $H\subseteq G$, then let topology be generated by $x\cdot H$ for $x\in G$. This is a non-trivial example when $H$ is non-trivial. Conversely, those are the only examples since if $U$ is the smallest neighbourhood of $1_G$ then necessarily $U\cdot U\subseteq U$ and $U^{-1}\subseteq U$. So Alexandrov topologies on a group correspond to its normal subgroups

There are however nontrivial Hausdorff topological groups which are $P$-spaces, meaning that every countable intersection of open sets is open

Theorem. For a group $G$, if $H\subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup then denote by $\tau_H$ the topology generated by taking $G/H = \{xH:x\in G\}$ as basis. Then the map $H\mapsto \tau_H$ is a bijection between normal subgroups of $G$ and topologies $\tau$ such that $(G, \tau)$ is an Alxandrov topological group.
Proof: Let $(G, \tau)$ be an Alexandrov topological group. If $H$ denotes intersection of all neighbourhoods of the neutral element $e$, then since $G$ is Alexandrov $H$ must be the smallest (open) neighbourhood of $e$. I claim that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Indeed, since $G$ is a topological group, there exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ such that $V\cdot V^{-1}\subseteq H$, and so $H\cdot H^{-1}\subseteq V\cdot V^{-1}\subseteq H$. That is, if $x, y\in H$ then $xy^{-1}\in H$, so $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. If $x\in U$ where $U$ is open then $xH\subseteq U$ so that $\tau\subseteq \tau_H$, and conversely $xH\in \tau$ for every $x\in G$. So $\tau = \tau_H$.
Now suppose that $H\subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Since $\tau_H$ is a topology generated by a partition of $G$, it is Alexandrov: if $U_i\in \tau_H$ and $x\in\bigcap_i U_i$ then since $xH$ is the only element of $G/H$ that $x$ belongs to, we need to have $xH\subseteq U_i$ for all $i$, and so $xH\subseteq \bigcap_i U_i$. And its a topological group, for if $x, y\in G$ and $U$ is a neighbourhood of $xy^{-1}$ then $(xH)(y^{-1}H) = xy^{-1}H\subseteq U$ which shows that $(x, y)\mapsto xy^{-1}$ is continuous. $\square$

If $H = \{e\}$ then $\tau_H$ is the discrete topology, if $H = G$ then $\tau_H$ is the indiscrete topology.
If $G$ isn't the trivial group or a simple group, then it admits topologies other than the two. For example if $G = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ then taking $H = \{0, 2\}$ we obtain a topology on $G$ which is neither discrete nor indiscrete.

If $(G, \tau)$ is an Alexandrov topological group which is $T_0$, then its $T_1$ and so discrete. But there exist Alexandrov topological spaces which are $T_0$ but not $T_1$, as Sierpiński space is an example.
